# Can I change the size or hide the row or track of a grid?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I have something as follows which is built in my Angular application through a set of loops. Think for example of a calendar which has  day at the left column, then it has one hour column, and each hour has an event (or more) in the following columns:

[image: Current status]

This is built with a grid like the following:

```html
<head>
    <style>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: 2rem;
        grid-auto-rows: 2rem;
        gap: 1rem;
    }

    .grid-item {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .multi-row{
        grid-row: span 4;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<div class="grid-container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="grid-item">Field 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Field 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Field 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Field 4</div>
    <!-- 1 row -->
    <div class="grid-item multi-row">Multi row</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item multi-row">Item 2</div>
    <!-- 2 row -->
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>

    <!-- 3 row -->
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>

    <!-- 4 row -->
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

To reduce the amount of space my table takes, there are some lines which I do not want to display because they do not have relevant content. For example imagine that you want to hide in the calendar the hours where there are no events, that line could be removed:
[image]

My question is how can I do that taking into account that the number of lines to be removed depends on the content of the cells in the row (which is being built dynamically) and that the row span of the `multi-row` items has to be adjusted to take into account those rows removed.